# Creating a routing in .NET Core 2.2 MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, routes, asp.net-core-2.2

I can't figure it out how to configurate a routing in the startup file.

That when you redirect to a view that has another controller the URL doesn't look like:

```
localhost/Success/Success/Success
```

Where the first Success is the controller, the second Success the View folder and the third Success the name of the View itself.

I would like something like this:

```
localhost/Sucess/Sucess
```

That the name of the controller is not shown in the URL.

I'm not using a link in the navigation page but a redirect:

```
return Redirect("Success/Success/Success");
```

startup.cs:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "success", template: "{controller=Success}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Comment: Can't understand your issue , why there is View folder `Success` ? MVC will auto find the view base on view name and controller .

Comment: If I don't create the folder "Success" it doesn't find the page...

Comment: Confirm your page name match action name , and view folder name matches controller name . Also , your description has `Sucess` and `Sucess` which seems odd .

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Success}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Comment: But I want to keep the default to controller Home. But add another routing with the Success controller

Comment: I see ok try this : 

routes.MapRoute(
                name: "success",
                template: "success/{controller=Success}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

Answer (score 0):

Try this - you can have multiple routes, but be aware they are order specific.

```
      routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default1",
            template: "{controller=Success}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

      routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default2",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```